RuntimeError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.Quiver
I am getting a RuntimeError while trying to launch Quiver on my trained Keras model. Despite specifying the input_shape, it still throws an error saying the layer has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.
Here is my model definition:
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, AveragePooling2D, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(6, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    AveragePooling2D(),
    Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu'),
    AveragePooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(120, activation='relu'),
    Dense(84, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()

And here is the error I am encountering when trying to launch Quiver:
RuntimeError: The layer sequential has never been called and thus has no defined input shape.
My launch code is:
from quiver_engine import server
server.launch(model, input_folder='./fashion_mnist_images')

I have verified that the input_shape is correctly specified in the model. What might be causing this error, and how can I fix it?
Error Stack Trace:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 1
----> 1 launch(model, input_folder='./fashion_mnist_images')

File ~/Desktop/enviroments/ai_env_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/quiver_engine/server.py:152, in launch(model, classes, top, temp_folder, input_folder, port, html_base_dir, mean, std)
    147 html_base_dir = html_base_dir if html_base_dir is not None else dirname(abspath(__file__))
    149 validate_launch(html_base_dir)
    151 return run_app(
--> 152     get_app(
    153         model, classes, top,
    154         html_base_dir=html_base_dir,
    155         temp_folder=temp_folder,
    156         input_folder=input_folder,
    157         mean=mean, std=std
    158     ),
    159     port
    160 )

File ~/Desktop/enviroments/ai_env_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/quiver_engine/server.py:47, in get_app(model, classes, top, html_base_dir, temp_folder, input_folder, mean, std)
     30 def get_app(model, classes, top, html_base_dir, temp_folder='./tmp', input_folder='./',
     31             mean=None, std=None):
     32     '''
     33     The base of the Flask application to be run
     34     :param model: the model to show
   (...)
     44     :return:
     45     '''
---> 47     single_input_shape, input_channels = get_input_config(model)
     49     app = Flask(__name__)
     50     app.threaded = True

File ~/Desktop/enviroments/ai_env_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/quiver_engine/util.py:42, in get_input_config(model)
     32 def get_input_config(model):
     33     '''
     34         returns a tuple (inputDimensions, numChannels)
     35     '''
     37     return (
     38         model.get_input_shape_at(0)[2:4],
     39         model.get_input_shape_at(0)[1]
     40     ) if K.image_data_format() == 'th' else (
     41         #tf ordering
---> 42         model.get_input_shape_at(0)[1:3],
     43         model.get_input_shape_at(0)[3]
     44     )

File ~/Desktop/enviroments/ai_env_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1999, in Layer.get_input_shape_at(self, node_index)
   1982 @doc_controls.do_not_doc_inheritable
   1983 def get_input_shape_at(self, node_index):
   1984     \"\"\"Retrieves the input shape(s) of a layer at a given node.
   1985 
   1986     Args:
   (...)
   1997       RuntimeError: If called in Eager mode.
   1998     \"\"\"
-> 1999     return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(
   2000         node_index, \"input_shapes\", \"input shape\"
   2001     )

File ~/Desktop/enviroments/ai_env_1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:2974, in Layer._get_node_attribute_at_index(self, node_index, attr, attr_name)
   2951 \"\"\"Private utility to retrieves an attribute (e.g. inputs) from a node.
   2952 
   2953 This is used to implement the methods:
   (...)
   2971     ValueError: If the index provided does not match any node.
   2972 \"\"\"
   2973 if not self._inbound_nodes:
-> 2974     raise RuntimeError(
   2975         f\"The layer {self.name} has never been called \"
   2976         f\"and thus has no defined {attr_name}.\"
   2977     )
   2978 if not len(self._inbound_nodes) > node_index:
   2979     raise ValueError(
   2980         f\"Asked to get {attr_name} at node \"
   2981         f\"{node_index}, but the layer has only \"
   2982         f\"{len(self._inbound_nodes)} inbound nodes.\"
   2983     )

